# How to write css code in javascript? (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property "height" of undefined)

Tags: javascript, css

How to write css code in javascript? (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property "height" of undefined)

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow").style.height = "86px";
```

**css**

```css
#slideshow .arrow{
    height:86px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    background:url('arrows.png') no-repeat;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -43px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: @Prabhu sure you can

Comment: @JamesDonnelly : didnt know thanks.

Comment: @Prabhu otherwise there would have been an error stating that getElementsByClassName is no method of that object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is the pluralisation of `getElementsByClassName` - element**s**. This method returns an array-like object of elements, not just one element.

To apply the style to each, you need to loop through this array-like object and add the styles to each individual element returned:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].style.height = "86px";
```

Comment: Or use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems,func)` or identify the element directly with `getElementsByClassName("arrow")[x]` with the according x.

Comment: This is a correct answer. It's similar to mine, but I was late. Well done :)

Comment: @Tibbers your answer has a lot of noise. A lot of that stuff is totally unrelated to the question. A straight to the point answer would perhaps have given you some upvotes. Also, referencing w3schools is a bad idea due to it's bad quality.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you for a feedback. I will keep it in mind and use it for future. Also deleted w3school reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array.

You have to loop through it, or if you know the index, do this:

`document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[0].style.height = "86px";`

or

`document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[i].style.height = "86px";`

`i` being your loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of theory:

**Changing HTML Style**

To change the style of an HTML element, use this syntax:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

Here is the example:

```js
// JavaScript demonstration
var changeBg = function (event) {
    console.log("method called");
    var me = event.target
    ,   square = document.getElementById("square");
    square.style.backgroundColor = "#ffaa44";
    me.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(clearDemo, 2000);
}

function clearDemo(button) {
    var square = document.getElementById("square");
    square.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", changeBg);
console.log(button);
```

```css
#square {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border: 2px inset gray;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
button {
    padding: .5em 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript sample</h1>
<div id="square"></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

**JavaScript-Based Style Sheets** - http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822 
**Mozzila's Web Developer guide** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript

While I've started with explanation and theory @James Donnelly already provided my answer, which I've wanted to use:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.height = "86px";
.
```

Comment: That's a big explanation, but does that answer the question ?

Comment: Yes it is. I've just started with explanation first and after that only with code. But James Donnelly answered it first. Anyway good luck.

Comment: Oh ok, when I asked, the last part of code wasn't there :)

Comment: Yep, I was finishing it :)

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out,

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array (**N Objects**)
while
document.getElementById returns an element (**ONE object**)

This is because **N** elements can have the same class but only **ONE** item can have a particular ID.

Since you can't edit more items' attribute at once, you must cycle them and edit the attribute of each one by one

```
document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[0].style.height = "86px";
document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[1].style.height = "86px";
document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[2].style.height = "86px";
.....
document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByClassName("arrow")[N].style.height = "86px";
```

This can be achieved by using a **for** cycle or a **each** one.